# Storing data from asp:listview to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have already done a lot of research about this here in stackoverflow and in the msdn documentation, however, nothing has helped. I need to be able to select an item in my asp: listview and take that text that I select and put it into a string to be used later. Here's the code of my .aspx:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Undécimo</a>
    <ul runat="server" id="eleventhList" class="sub-menu">
        <asp:ListView ID="listViewforEleventh" runat="server" OnItemCommand="listViewforEleventh_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a onserverclick="linkForEleven_ServerClick" runat="server" id="linkForEleven" href="ViewSchedule.aspx"> <asp:Label ID="eleventhGroupLabel" runat="server" Text="<%#Container.DataItem %>"></asp:Label> </a>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="dataString"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I'm populating the list view like this:

```
private void loadEleventh()
{
    list = group.getGroupsByLevelService(11);
    List<string> sublist = new List<string>();
    foreach (var element in list)
        sublist.Add(element.GroupName);
    listViewforEleventh.DataSource = sublist;
    listViewforEleventh.DataBind();
}
```

This works, but now I need to select the data (text) that is in the sp:ListView. I am doing it like this:

```
protected void linkForEleven_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewDataItem item = listViewforEleventh.Items[listViewforEleventh.SelectedIndex];
    Label c = (Label)item.FindControl("dataString");
    groupName = c.Text;
}
```

When I debugged my code I got an error of index out of range exception in the selectedIndex method with the value -1. How can I solve this? Or how can I take the data from the listview item and store it in a string in another way?

Comment: if listViewforEleventh.SelectedIndex is -1 it means there is no row selected... i belive it's because you're firing an event on the item template and it's being processed without selecting the row. YOu can perfectly remove that anchor and just hook to the "SelectedIndexChanged" from the list

Answer (score 0):

In your `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler, do this:

```
string valueToSave = YourListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Of course, you have to make sure that you have actually selected an item in the `ListBox` in order for there to be a value for `YourListbox.SelectedValue`. This is just an example of how to do this once. I don't know the details behind how you want to use this value, of course.

Comment: so in other words i need to change onitemcommand for selectedItemChange?

Comment: Instead of `OnItemCommand`, try `SelectedIndexChanged = listViewforEleventh_ItemCommand` in your .`aspx` file.

Comment: if i do just that then i recieve a invalidOperationException, so i´ll need a dataKeyNames to specify the values that i want to get. I have a general idea now of how to do it.. thanks... if  i need help again i´ll bother you again, sorry bro

Comment: Make sure that you have bound the event handler for `SelectedIndexChanged` in the designer.

Comment: well i resolved the issue by making a onItemCommand event in the asp:listview control. that hot the ring. Anyway thanks for the advises